# how to call a javascript function in grails 2.2.2

Tags: javascript, grails

I am trying to call my javascript function but its not working.. Please help me out

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function confirm(){
            alert('hello world');
    }
});
</script>
```

textbox code:

```
<div class="full-filed">
            <h3>Confirm Password:</h3>
        </div>      
        <g:passwordField name="confirm" value="" class="loginTxtBox" placeholder="Password" onClick="confirm();"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function is available only inside `ready(..)` function. You have to define your funciton in main context:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm(){
    alert('hello world');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler apprach is to attach the event in the element using JQuery. Also, javascript already have a function called `confirm` so I suggest you to change this name:

```
function confirmClick() {
  alert('click!');
}

$(function(){
  //attach a click event to the element with id 'pass'.
  $('#pass').click(function(){
    confirmClick();
  });
});
```

And your field should have the id:

```
<g:passwordField name="confirm" value="" class="loginTxtBox" placeholder="Password" id="pass" />
```